# Access to config.action_controller.perform_caching value from inside a controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Is it possible to check the value of:

```
config.action_controller.perform_caching
```

...from within ApplicationController?

I have some custom caching methods that should or shouldn't be called based on this value.

Answer (score 1):

```
ActionController::Base.perform_caching
```

returns true or false depending on whether the caching is enabled.

Answer (score 0):

As of Rails 3.x, you can use this:

```
Rails.configuration.action_controller.perform_caching
```